# Angular UI-Grid - Pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, nested

I have a hierarchical structure that needs to be displayed in a table format. I am using UI-GRID ( http://ui-grid.info/) for implementing it.

The structure is something like

```
GrandParent Level 0 
   Parent   Level 1
     Child  Level2
OrphanRecord1 Level 0 
OrphanRecord2 Level 0
OrphanRecord2 Level 0
```

My requirement is to implement pagination with say 2 items per page. 
In the above Structure, I want GrandParent1 to be displayed in the first page along with OrphanRecord1 and OrphanRecord2, 3 to be displayed in the second page.

When the user expands the GrandParent1, then all child records under GrandParent1 should be displayed in page1 itself .

I am unable to show a Plunker for some strange reason.

How to get this using UI-GRID?

Currently with page size of 2, when I expand the GrandParent1 row, then the display changes to GrandParent1 and Parent1. The Child and Orphanrecord1 are then shown in Page 2. Basically the structure is getting broken to accommodate the pagesize request whereas I want the structure to be retained.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hDsfHbo4nKCvCGglWC7Z?p=preview  .   Here is the Plunker.

Comment: does anyone have a solution to this problem